# rvest scraping incomplete html table

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape `#tournametTable` from this website: https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

read_html("https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/") %>%
  html_node(., "#tournamentTable") %>%
  html_table(.)
```

The results are incomplete, I only get some of the data contained in the table. After reading around on StackOverflow, I suspect that I'm either doing something wrong, or that this table requires a special approach for `rvest` to fetch all the data.

How do I get all of the data contained within the table body using rvest?

Comment: what do you mean by incomplete data? I get 48 rows and 7 columns. What are you expecting?

Comment: Do you get the actual betting odds though? All I'm seeing is the fixture, and the subheaders (1, X, 2, Bs).

Comment: ahh..I seee..No, I get just `-`'s. I think those are loaded with javascript.